# VS2015 won´t build cordova app on Android device

Tags: android, visual-studio, cordova, visual-studio-2015

**Visual Studio 2015** won´t build my cordova app on my Android Device. Everything is set up including Google usb driver, adb sees my device, usb debugging on.

Here´s my Ouput:

```
1>------ Build started: Project: BlankCordovaApp2, Configuration: Debug Android ------
1>Build started 16-9-2015 21:42:43.
1>InstallMDA:
1>  Your environment has been set up for using Node.js 0.12.2 (ia32) and npm.
1>  ------ Ensuring correct global installation of package from source package directory: C:\PROGRAM FILES (X86)\MICROSOFT VISUAL STUDIO 14.0\COMMON7\IDE\EXTENSIONS\APACHECORDOVATOOLS\packages\vs-tac
1>  ------ Name from source package.json: vs-tac
1>  ------ Version from source package.json: 1.0.4
1>  ------ Package already installed globally at correct version.
1>BuildMDA:
1>  ------ Cordova tools 5.1.1 already installed.
1>  ------ Build Settings:
1>  ------ Build Settings:
1>  ------    platformConfigurationBldDir: C:\Users\Justi\OneDrive\Websites\Phone\BlankCordovaApp2\BlankCordovaApp2\bld\Android\Debug
1>  ------    platformConfigurationBinDir: C:\Users\Justi\OneDrive\Websites\Phone\BlankCordovaApp2\BlankCordovaApp2\bin\Android\Debug
1>  ------    buildCommand: build
1>  ------    platform: Android
1>  ------    cordovaPlatform: android
1>  ------    configuration: Debug
1>  ------    cordovaConfiguration: Debug
1>  ------    projectName: BlankCordovaApp2
1>  ------    projectSourceDir: C:\Users\Justi\OneDrive\Websites\Phone\BlankCordovaApp2\BlankCordovaApp2
1>  ------    npmInstallDir: C:\Users\Justi\AppData\Roaming\npm
1>  ------    buildTarget: AndroidEmulator
1>  ------    language: en-US
1>  ------    changeList.changedFilesIos: bower.json,res\icons\android\icon-72-hdpi.png,res\screens\android\screen-mdpi-landscape.png,merges\android\scripts\android2.3-jscompat.js,merges\windows\scripts\winstore-jscompat.js,res\icons\ios\icon-60.png,res\screens\ios\screen-iphone-landscape-736h.png,res\icons\windows\StoreLogo.scale-100.png,www\scripts\index.js,res\icons\android\icon-48-mdpi.png,res\icons\ios\icon-72.png,res\icons\ios\icon-76.png,res\screens\ios\screen-ipad-portrait-2x.png,plugins\cordova-plugin-whitelist\NOTICE,res\screens\ios\screen-iphone-portrait-2x.png,res\icons\windows\Square71x71Logo.scale-240.png,merges\android\scripts\platformOverrides.js,plugins\cordova-plugin-whitelist\src\android\WhitelistPlugin.java,res\screens\android\screen-hdpi-portrait.png,www\css\index.css,res\icons\windows\StoreLogo.scale-240.png,res\screens\ios\screen-ipad-landscape.png,res\icons\ios\icon-60-3x.png,plugins\cordova-plugin-whitelist\whitelist.js,plugins\fetch.json,config.xml,res\screens\wp8\SplashScreenImage.jpg,res\screens\ios\screen-ipad-landscape-2x.png,res\screens\ios\screen-iphone-568h-2x.png,res\icons\windows\Square150x150Logo.scale-100.png,package.json,res\screens\android\screen-ldpi-landscape.png,res\icons\windows\Wide310x150Logo.scale-240.png,res\icons\windows\Wide310x150Logo.scale-100.png,res\icons\ios\icon-72-2x.png,res\icons\ios\icon-76-2x.png,res\icons\ios\icon-small.png,res\icons\windows\Square30x30Logo.scale-100.png,plugins\cordova-plugin-whitelist\plugin.xml,res\icons\wp8\Background.png,www\index.html,res\icons\ios\icon-40.png,res\icons\ios\icon-60-2x.png,res\screens\android\screen-ldpi-portrait.png,plugins\cordova-plugin-whitelist\package.json,plugins\cordova-plugin-whitelist\CONTRIBUTING.md,res\native\android\ant.properties,res\icons\windows\Square310x310Logo.scale-100.png,www\scripts\platformOverrides.js,taco.json,res\icons\windows\Square150x150Logo.scale-240.png,res\icons\android\icon-36-ldpi.png,merges\windows\scripts\platformOverrides.js,res\screens\ios\screen-iphone-portrait.png,Project_Readme.html,res\screens\android\screen-xhdpi-portrait.png,res\icons\ios\icon-50-2x.png,res\icons\ios\icon-57-2x.png,res\icons\ios\icon-50.png,res\icons\ios\icon-57.png,res\icons\ios\icon-small-2x.png,plugins\cordova-plugin-whitelist\LICENSE,res\icons\windows\Square70x70Logo.scale-100.png,res\screens\windows\SplashScreen.scale-240.png,plugins\cordova-plugin-whitelist\src\ios\CDVNavigationWhitelistPlugin.h,res\icons\android\icon-96-xhdpi.png,res\icons\wp8\ApplicationIcon.png,res\icons\ios\icon-40-2x.png,res\screens\ios\screen-iphone-portrait-667h.png,res\screens\android\screen-hdpi-landscape.png,res\screens\windows\SplashScreenPhone.scale-240.png,res\screens\windows\SplashScreen.scale-100.png,res\screens\ios\screen-iphone-portrait-736h.png,res\screens\ios\screen-ipad-portrait.png,plugins\cordova-plugin-whitelist\RELEASENOTES.md,res\screens\android\screen-xhdpi-landscape.png,plugins\cordova-plugin-whitelist\src\ios\CDVNavigationWhitelistPlugin.m,plugins\cordova-plugin-whitelist\README.md,res\icons\windows\Square44x44Logo.scale-240.png,res\screens\android\screen-mdpi-portrait.png
1>  ------    changeList.deletedFilesIos:
1>  ------    changeList.addedPluginsIos:
1>  ------    changeList.deletedPluginsIos:
1>  ------    changeList.addedPlugins:
1>  ------    changeList.deletedPlugins:
1>  ------ Platform android already exists
1>  ------ Copying native files from C:\Users\Justi\OneDrive\Websites\Phone\BlankCordovaApp2\BlankCordovaApp2\res\native\android to platforms\android
1>  ------ Done copying native files to platforms\android
1>  ------ Updating plugins
1>  ------ Currently installed plugins: cordova-plugin-whitelist@1.0.0
1>  ------ Currently installed dependent plugins:
1>  ------ Currently configured plugins:
1>  ------ Preparing platform: android
1>  Generating config.xml from defaults for platform "android"
1>  Calling plugman.prepare for platform "android"
1>  Preparing android project
1>  Processing configuration changes for plugins.
1>  Iterating over installed plugins: [ 'cordova-plugin-whitelist' ]
1>  Writing out cordova_plugins.js...
1>  Wrote out Android application name to "BlankCordovaApp2"
1>  deleted: C:\Users\Justi\OneDrive\Websites\Phone\BlankCordovaApp2\BlankCordovaApp2\platforms\android\res\drawable-land-hdpi\screen.png
1>  deleted: C:\Users\Justi\OneDrive\Websites\Phone\BlankCordovaApp2\BlankCordovaApp2\platforms\android\res\drawable-land-ldpi\screen.png
1>  deleted: C:\Users\Justi\OneDrive\Websites\Phone\BlankCordovaApp2\BlankCordovaApp2\platforms\android\res\drawable-land-mdpi\screen.png
1>  deleted: C:\Users\Justi\OneDrive\Websites\Phone\BlankCordovaApp2\BlankCordovaApp2\platforms\android\res\drawable-land-xhdpi\screen.png
1>  deleted: C:\Users\Justi\OneDrive\Websites\Phone\BlankCordovaApp2\BlankCordovaApp2\platforms\android\res\drawable-port-hdpi\screen.png
1>  deleted: C:\Users\Justi\OneDrive\Websites\Phone\BlankCordovaApp2\BlankCordovaApp2\platforms\android\res\drawable-port-ldpi\screen.png
1>  deleted: C:\Users\Justi\OneDrive\Websites\Phone\BlankCordovaApp2\BlankCordovaApp2\platforms\android\res\drawable-port-mdpi\screen.png
1>  deleted: C:\Users\Justi\OneDrive\Websites\Phone\BlankCordovaApp2\BlankCordovaApp2\platforms\android\res\drawable-port-xhdpi\screen.png
1>  splash screens: [{"src":"res/screens/android/screen-hdpi-landscape.png","density":"land-hdpi","platform":"android"},{"src":"res/screens/android/screen-ldpi-landscape.png","density":"land-ldpi","platform":"android"},{"src":"res/screens/android/screen-mdpi-landscape.png","density":"land-mdpi","platform":"android"},{"src":"res/screens/android/screen-xhdpi-landscape.png","density":"land-xhdpi","platform":"android"},{"src":"res/screens/android/screen-hdpi-portrait.png","density":"port-hdpi","platform":"android"},{"src":"res/screens/android/screen-ldpi-portrait.png","density":"port-ldpi","platform":"android"},{"src":"res/screens/android/screen-mdpi-portrait.png","density":"port-mdpi","platform":"android"},{"src":"res/screens/android/screen-xhdpi-portrait.png","density":"port-xhdpi","platform":"android"}]
1>  copying image from C:\Users\Justi\OneDrive\Websites\Phone\BlankCordovaApp2\BlankCordovaApp2\res\screens\android\screen-hdpi-landscape.png to C:\Users\Justi\OneDrive\Websites\Phone\BlankCordovaApp2\BlankCordovaApp2\platforms\android\res\drawable-land-hdpi\screen.png
1>  copying image from C:\Users\Justi\OneDrive\Websites\Phone\BlankCordovaApp2\BlankCordovaApp2\res\screens\android\screen-ldpi-landscape.png to C:\Users\Justi\OneDrive\Websites\Phone\BlankCordovaApp2\BlankCordovaApp2\platforms\android\res\drawable-land-ldpi\screen.png
1>  copying image from C:\Users\Justi\OneDrive\Websites\Phone\BlankCordovaApp2\BlankCordovaApp2\res\screens\android\screen-mdpi-landscape.png to C:\Users\Justi\OneDrive\Websites\Phone\BlankCordovaApp2\BlankCordovaApp2\platforms\android\res\drawable-land-mdpi\screen.png
1>  copying image from C:\Users\Justi\OneDrive\Websites\Phone\BlankCordovaApp2\BlankCordovaApp2\res\screens\android\screen-xhdpi-landscape.png to C:\Users\Justi\OneDrive\Websites\Phone\BlankCordovaApp2\BlankCordovaApp2\platforms\android\res\drawable-land-xhdpi\screen.png
1>  copying image from C:\Users\Justi\OneDrive\Websites\Phone\BlankCordovaApp2\BlankCordovaApp2\res\screens\android\screen-hdpi-portrait.png to C:\Users\Justi\OneDrive\Websites\Phone\BlankCordovaApp2\BlankCordovaApp2\platforms\android\res\drawable-port-hdpi\screen.png
1>  copying image from C:\Users\Justi\OneDrive\Websites\Phone\BlankCordovaApp2\BlankCordovaApp2\res\screens\android\screen-ldpi-portrait.png to C:\Users\Justi\OneDrive\Websites\Phone\BlankCordovaApp2\BlankCordovaApp2\platforms\android\res\drawable-port-ldpi\screen.png
1>  copying image from C:\Users\Justi\OneDrive\Websites\Phone\BlankCordovaApp2\BlankCordovaApp2\res\screens\android\screen-mdpi-portrait.png to C:\Users\Justi\OneDrive\Websites\Phone\BlankCordovaApp2\BlankCordovaApp2\platforms\android\res\drawable-port-mdpi\screen.png
1>  copying image from C:\Users\Justi\OneDrive\Websites\Phone\BlankCordovaApp2\BlankCordovaApp2\res\screens\android\screen-xhdpi-portrait.png to C:\Users\Justi\OneDrive\Websites\Phone\BlankCordovaApp2\BlankCordovaApp2\platforms\android\res\drawable-port-xhdpi\screen.png
1>  deleted: C:\Users\Justi\OneDrive\Websites\Phone\BlankCordovaApp2\BlankCordovaApp2\platforms\android\res\drawable-hdpi\icon.png
1>  deleted: C:\Users\Justi\OneDrive\Websites\Phone\BlankCordovaApp2\BlankCordovaApp2\platforms\android\res\drawable-ldpi\icon.png
1>  deleted: C:\Users\Justi\OneDrive\Websites\Phone\BlankCordovaApp2\BlankCordovaApp2\platforms\android\res\drawable-mdpi\icon.png
1>  deleted: C:\Users\Justi\OneDrive\Websites\Phone\BlankCordovaApp2\BlankCordovaApp2\platforms\android\res\drawable-xhdpi\icon.png
1>  copying image from C:\Users\Justi\OneDrive\Websites\Phone\BlankCordovaApp2\BlankCordovaApp2\res\icons\android\icon-36-ldpi.png to C:\Users\Justi\OneDrive\Websites\Phone\BlankCordovaApp2\BlankCordovaApp2\platforms\android\res\drawable-ldpi\icon.png
1>  copying image from C:\Users\Justi\OneDrive\Websites\Phone\BlankCordovaApp2\BlankCordovaApp2\res\icons\android\icon-48-mdpi.png to C:\Users\Justi\OneDrive\Websites\Phone\BlankCordovaApp2\BlankCordovaApp2\platforms\android\res\drawable-mdpi\icon.png
1>  copying image from C:\Users\Justi\OneDrive\Websites\Phone\BlankCordovaApp2\BlankCordovaApp2\res\icons\android\icon-72-hdpi.png to C:\Users\Justi\OneDrive\Websites\Phone\BlankCordovaApp2\BlankCordovaApp2\platforms\android\res\drawable-hdpi\icon.png
1>  copying image from C:\Users\Justi\OneDrive\Websites\Phone\BlankCordovaApp2\BlankCordovaApp2\res\icons\android\icon-96-xhdpi.png to C:\Users\Justi\OneDrive\Websites\Phone\BlankCordovaApp2\BlankCordovaApp2\platforms\android\res\drawable-xhdpi\icon.png
1>  Wrote out Android package name to "io.cordova.myappa9065d"
1>  ------ Copied C:\Users\Justi\OneDrive\Websites\Phone\BlankCordovaApp2\BlankCordovaApp2\bin\Android\Debug\VSBuildInfo.xml to platforms\android\assets\www\VSBuildInfo.xml
1>  ------ Building platform: android
1>  Debug
1>  ------ Build configuration options: --debug
1>  Running command: cmd "/s /c "C:\Users\Justi\OneDrive\Websites\Phone\BlankCordovaApp2\BlankCordovaApp2\platforms\android\cordova\build.bat --debug""
1>  ANDROID_HOME=C:\Users\Justi\AppData\Local\Android\android-sdk
1>  JAVA_HOME=C:\Program Files (x86)\Java\jdk1.7.0_55
1>  Running: C:\Users\Justi\OneDrive\Websites\Phone\BlankCordovaApp2\BlankCordovaApp2\platforms\android\gradlew cdvBuildDebug -b C:\Users\Justi\OneDrive\Websites\Phone\BlankCordovaApp2\BlankCordovaApp2\platforms\android\build.gradle -Dorg.gradle.daemon=true
1>
1>  FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.
1>
1>  * What went wrong:
1>  java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid LOC header (bad signature)
1>
1>  * Try:
1>  Run with --stacktrace option to get the stack trace. Run with --info or --debug option to get more log output.
1>  Picked up _JAVA_OPTIONS: -Xmx512M
1>
1>  C:\Users\Justi\OneDrive\Websites\Phone\BlankCordovaApp2\BlankCordovaApp2\platforms\android\cordova\node_modules\q\q.js:126
1>                      throw e;
1>                            ^
1>  Error code 1 for command: cmd with args: /s /c "C:\Users\Justi\OneDrive\Websites\Phone\BlankCordovaApp2\BlankCordovaApp2\platforms\android\gradlew cdvBuildDebug -b C:\Users\Justi\OneDrive\Websites\Phone\BlankCordovaApp2\BlankCordovaApp2\platforms\android\build.gradle -Dorg.gradle.daemon=true"
1>  Command finished with error code 1: cmd /s /c "C:\Users\Justi\OneDrive\Websites\Phone\BlankCordovaApp2\BlankCordovaApp2\platforms\android\cordova\build.bat --debug"
1>MDAVSCLI : error : cmd: Command failed with exit code 1
1>ERROR building one of the platforms : error : cmd: Command failed with exit code 1
1>  You may not have the required environment or OS to build this project
1>
1>Build FAILED.
1>
1>Time Elapsed 00:00:02.44
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
========== Deploy: 0 succeeded, 0 failed, 0 skipped ==========
```

This seems to be the badboy:
**java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid LOC header (bad signature)** 

I have no clue what the problem is. Can you please help me out? D:

Comment: zip's corrupted somehow. possibly: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3804505/reading-zip-file-gives-an-invalid-loc-header-exception

Comment: I have the latest Java version installed, that should be right, no? @MarcB